# How to make a picture using Racket

Tags: racket

I am new at using Racket and have a question that seems pretty simple.
Basically what I need to do is make a scene/picture using Racket. My first step is I want to have a moon, grass, and a background in the same picture.

Should/can I use E-SCENE for that or should I just use overlay?

I've been trying to figure this out for so long. Everytime I do it the moon and background come out as one and the background and grass show up as a different one. Here is what I have so far (not using empty-scene):

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define rectangle1 (rectangle 450 400 "solid" "midnight blue"))
(define circle1 (circle 50 "solid" "WhiteSmoke"))
(place-image circle1 (/ 450 6) (* 400 .15) rectangle1)
(define rectangle2 (rectangle 450 30 "solid" "forest green"))
(place-image rectangle2 (/ 450 2) 400 rectangle1)
(define background (overlay rectangle2 circle1 rectangle1))
```

Comment: Don't think of `place-image` as an effect; think of it as a function that takes data and returns new data, just like `+` taking two numbers and returning a number. If you pretend for a moment that `+` only takes 2 numbers, then to add 3 numbers you have to *nest* them like `(+ 1 (+ 2 3))`. In the same way, to combine 3 images with `place-image` you have to *nest* them like `(place-image image1 x1 y1 (place-image image2 x2 y2 image3))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of `place-image` as an effect; think of it as a function that takes data and returns new data, just like `+` taking two numbers and returning a number. If you pretend for a moment that `+` only takes 2 numbers, then to add 3 numbers together with `+` you have to *nest* them:

```
(+ 1 (+ 2 3))
```

The `place-image` function only combines 2 images, so in the same way we nested the `+` calls above to combine 3 numbers, to combine 3 images together with `place-image` you have to *nest* the `place-image` calls:

```
(place-image image1 x1 y1
             (place-image image2 x2 y2
                          image3))
```

For your code this means:

```
(place-image circle1 (/ 450 6) (* 400 .15)
             (place-image rectangle2 (/ 450 2) 400
                          rectangle1))
```

Which combines the three images together to produce:

[image: Nested place-image to combine 3 images]

Similarly to combine even more things together, for numbers:

```
(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (+ 4 5))))
```

And for images:

```
(place-image image1 x1 y1
             (place-image image2 x2 y2
                          (place-image image3 x3 y3
                                       (place-image image4 x4 y4
                                                    image5))))
```

**NOTE:** For numbers you normally don't have to do this. `(+ 1 2 3 4 5)` works just as well as `(+ 1 (+ 2 ...))`.